# Assembly Language: Two-prompt user input (mix char and int)

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am new to assembly programming and need help understanding and fixing some code I have been struggling with:
I want to provide user input:

Prompt 1: Enter destination
read value
prompt 2: Enter destination
read value
Display Distance and Destination.

I am using VS2012 with Irvine32 libraries on an x64 hardware. I am compiling as x32.

**The problem**
The code compiles and builds. But the output is not proper. The first prompt is only displayed with no input. The second prompt "Distance" is displayed with entry allowed. If I change the first prompt to have a "readInt" instead of "readString", I get prompts in both, but I would get "Invalid Integer" error. Why is this? How do I fix this and also display the input values.

**My code**

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc

;*************************************************************************      
.data
    queryDest   byte   "Destination", 0
    queryDist   byte   "Distance", 0

    destination       dword   ?
    distance       dword   ?

.code
 main proc
        call clrscr

        mov edx, offset queryDest
        call writeString
        call readString
        mov destination, eax

        call crlf
        mov edx, offset queryDist
        call writeString
        call readInt
        mov distance, eax

        call crlf
        Call WaitMsg        ;causes a wait for a key to be pressed
        exit
main endp
end main
```

**Current output**

*Destination*

*Distance50*

*Press any key to continue...*

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I am new to Aseembly. I am trying to understand what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested because my VS 2012 refuses to work (working on it). Your main problem is that `destination` must be a string, not a number :

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc

;*************************************************************************      
.data
    queryDest   byte   "Destination=", 0
    queryDist   byte   "Distance=", 0

    destination byte   "                     " ; LENGTH 21.
    distance    dword   ?

.code
 main proc
        call clrscr
 ;READ DESTINATION.    
        mov edx, offset queryDest
        call writeString             ;DISPLAY MESSAGE.

        mov edx, offset destination  ;STORE STRING HERE (ZERO TERMINATED).
        mov ecx, 20                  ;MAX CHARS TO READ.
        call readString              ;STORES STRING WHERE EDX POINTS.

        call crlf
 ;READ DISTANCE.
        mov edx, offset queryDist
        call writeString             ;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
        call readInt
        mov distance, eax

 ;DISPLAY DESTINATION AND DISTANCE.
        call crlf
        call crlf
        mov edx, offset destination   ;EDX POINTS TO STRING TO DISPLAY.
        call writeString              ;DISPLAY DESTINATION.
        call crlf
        mov eax, distance             ;NUMBER TO DISPLAY.
        call writeInt                 ;DISPLAY DISTANCE.

        call crlf
        Call WaitMsg        ;causes a wait for a key to be pressed
        exit
main endp
end main
```

[Bibliography](http://ocw.kfupm.edu.sa/ocw_courses/user062/COE2055253/Lecture%20Notes/05-InputOutput.pdf)

Comment: It is complaining of "error A2084: constant value too large" on "destination byte   "                     " // LENGTH 21."

Comment: Most helpful. Thanks @jose

Comment: @Sylvester, apologies, I have been working on PHP where comments are `//` (oops!).